# migrating entire set of attributes and attribute sets to a fresh installation

Tags: attributes, ee-1.13, attribute-set, migration

I have a rather large set of attributes and a dozen attribute sets that I need to migrate to a  fresh installation of Magento of the same version down the road. I'd like to do this without carrying over the attribute values theselves.

Has anyone done this safely? I have exported-imported the `eav_*` and `catalog_eav_attribute` in the past to move all attribute-related data while testing some things, and it seemed to have work without problems that I could notice. But what if I want to just perfectly copy over attributes, attribute sets, and no attribute values that are new to the fresh installation (i.e. no products)?

Comment: did you ever complete this? I would be interested if you had any issues.

Comment: I had tried copying the tables at first, and it seemed to be fine. However, I quickly decided to just write a Magento shell script to recreate the attributes and sets in order to avoid any problems down the road.

Comment: feel free to post how you did this as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had to deal with this kind of issue once.

Possible ways of migrating the attributes and attribute-sets to a **fresh** (!!) installation:

**Copying tables to the new database**

As the OP already already mentioned, copying the `eav_*` and `catalog_eav_attribute` is a possible option.

**Creating setup scripts to execute on the new installation**

This is the best-practise way in this case. The OP mentioned Magento shell scripts above, but I guess Magento **setup/data scripts** where meant.
Create a new module, add a setup or a data resource and add your script(s) which contain the code to generate your attributes and attribute sets.

You can have a look at the `eav_setup` and `catalog_setup` how Magento sets up the default attributes & attribute sets.

**Use SOAP**

If you don't have/cannot get access to the second magento installation, you could think about writing a SOAP-script to retrieve the attributes and attribute-sets.
This is not the fastest option of all, but still a possibility. Be aware that the functions of the SOAP API is limited.

*Personal note: I think I can remember that I have encountered some issues with the attribute groups, so you might need to extend the SOAP functions at least a bit.*